# opencl - resources for multiple commandqueues

Tags: parallel-processing, task, opencl

I'm working on an application where I real-time process a video feed on my GPU and once in a while I need to do some resource extensive calculations on my GPU besides that. My problem now is that I want to keep my video processing at real-time speed while doing the extra work in parallel once it comes up.

The way I think this should be done is with two command-queues, one for the real time video processing and one for the extensive calculations. However, I have no idea how this will turn out with the computing resources of the GPU: will there be equally many workers assigned to the command-queues during parallel execution? (so I could expect a slowdown of about 50% of my real-time computations?) Or is it device dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenCL specification leaves it up to the vendor to decide how to balance execution resources between multiple command queues.  So a vendor could implement OpenCL in such a way that causes the GPU to work on only one kernel at a time.  That would be a legal implementation, in my opinion.

If you really want to solve your problem in a device-independent way, I think you need to figure out how to break up your large non-real-time computation into smaller computations.

Answer (score 1):

AMD has some extensions (some of which I think got adopted in OpenCL 1.2) for device fission, which means you can reserve some portion of the device for one context and use the rest for others.